# Minimum sdk for recycleview and pros/cons of replacing listviews with it

Tags: android, listview, android-recyclerview

What is the minimum sdk currently for `recyclerview`. I've seen some posts about this but they're all from 2014 so I'm looking for some new info. Also, my app is heavily dependent on `listviews` and `asynctasks` and I'm thinking of switching to `recyclerview` to add some animations etc. My min sdk is 11 for the app and I'm wondering whether this change is possible or will it cause compatibility issues. Also, is the process of converting from a listview to a recyclerview time consuming or not?

Comment: The RecyclerView is in the v7 support library which is available for api levels above 7.

Comment: you can easily convert ListView into Recyclerview , just need to change declaration in xml and define RecyclerView.Adapter , the rest depends on your code ,

Answer (score 15, accepted):

RecyclerView is part of the `v7` support library which means you can use it on anything that has api 7 and up.

the process of converting is not trivial but its not hard either